# Draw a Houndstooth Pattern

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a program or function that takes in two positive integers, a width and a height, and draws an ASCII art [houndstooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houndstooth) grid pattern with those dimensions using this 25×26 text grid as the base cell:

```
.......#.....#####.......
.......##.....#####......
.......###.....#####.....
.......####.....####.....
.......#####.....###.....
.......######.....##.....
.......#######.....#.....
.......########..........
####################.....
.####################....
..####################...
...####################..
....####################.
.....####################
#.....##############.####
##.....#############..###
###....#############...##
####...#############....#
#####..#############.....
.#####.#############.....
..##################.....
........#####............
.........#####...........
..........#####..........
...........#####.........
............#####........
```

So if the input was `2,1` the output would be:

```
.......#.....#####..............#.....#####.......
.......##.....#####.............##.....#####......
.......###.....#####............###.....#####.....
.......####.....####............####.....####.....
.......#####.....###............#####.....###.....
.......######.....##............######.....##.....
.......#######.....#............#######.....#.....
.......########.................########..........
####################.....####################.....
.####################.....####################....
..####################.....####################...
...####################.....####################..
....####################.....####################.
.....####################.....####################
#.....##############.#####.....##############.####
##.....#############..#####.....#############..###
###....#############...#####....#############...##
####...#############....#####...#############....#
#####..#############.....#####..#############.....
.#####.#############......#####.#############.....
..##################.......##################.....
........#####....................#####............
.........#####....................#####...........
..........#####....................#####..........
...........#####....................#####.........
............#####....................#####........
```

And if the input was `5,4` the output would be:

```
.......#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####.......
.......##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####......
.......###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####.....
.......####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####.....
.......#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###.....
.......######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##.....
.......#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#.....
.......########.................########.................########.................########.................########..........
####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....
.####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################....
..####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################...
...####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################..
....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.
.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################
#.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.####
##.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..###
###....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...##
####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#
#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....
.#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############.....
..##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.....
........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####............
.........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####...........
..........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####..........
...........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####.........
............#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####........
.......#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####.......
.......##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####......
.......###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####.....
.......####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####.....
.......#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###.....
.......######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##.....
.......#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#.....
.......########.................########.................########.................########.................########..........
####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....
.####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################....
..####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################...
...####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################..
....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.
.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################
#.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.####
##.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..###
###....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...##
####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#
#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....
.#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############.....
..##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.....
........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####............
.........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####...........
..........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####..........
...........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####.........
............#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####........
.......#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####.......
.......##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####......
.......###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####.....
.......####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####.....
.......#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###.....
.......######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##.....
.......#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#.....
.......########.................########.................########.................########.................########..........
####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....
.####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################....
..####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################...
...####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################..
....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.
.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################
#.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.####
##.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..###
###....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...##
####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#
#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....
.#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############.....
..##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.....
........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####............
.........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####...........
..........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####..........
...........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####.........
............#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####........
.......#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####..............#.....#####.......
.......##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####.............##.....#####......
.......###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####............###.....#####.....
.......####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####............####.....####.....
.......#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###............#####.....###.....
.......######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##............######.....##.....
.......#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#............#######.....#.....
.......########.................########.................########.................########.................########..........
####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....
.####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################....
..####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################...
...####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################..
....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.
.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################.....####################
#.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.#####.....##############.####
##.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..#####.....#############..###
###....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...#####....#############...##
####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#####...#############....#
#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....#####..#############.....
.#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############......#####.#############.....
..##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.......##################.....
........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####............
.........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####...........
..........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####..........
...........#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####.........
............#####....................#####....................#####....................#####....................#####........
```

- The width argument must come first. Any reasonable input format (e.g. `w,h`, `w h`, `(w, h)`) is fine.
- Print or return the result with an optional trailing newline.
- You may use any two distinct [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters in place of `.` and `#`.
- You can translate the base cell vertically or horizontally, as if it had [periodic boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions). Thus the top left corner of the output will not necessarily be a 7×8 rectangle of `.`'s. (**New rule!**)

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

As a bonus, generate an image instead where each `.` is a pixel of one color and each `#` is a pixel of another color.

Comment: What kind of bonus? A cookie..? ;-)

Comment: Screw your "shortest code wins", I'm Befunge'ing this!

Comment: @ZachGates Maybe a dog biscuit.

Comment: Roll Tide to that!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>61</s> <s>60</s> <s>55</s> 49 bytes

```
j*vwmjk*Qd++Rm012Jmms}k++Rhd5U-d4T=T13+Lm1T_mP_dJ
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j*vwmjk*Qd%2B%2BRm012Jmms%7Dk%2B%2BRhd5U-d4T%3DT13%2BLm1T_mP_dJ&input=5%0A4&debug=0)

edit 1: Combine the two statements generating the band and the triangle (see below)

edit 2: Didn't saw that we can use any symbols. Saved 5 bytes
edit

edit 3: @Calvin'sHobbies allowed translating the base image. Since my approach was based on this idea, this helped quite a lot. -6 bytes

And for the **Cookie bonus**:

```
.w*vw*RQ++Rm012Jmm*K255}k++Rhd5U-d4T=T13+LmKT_mP_dJ
```

This is only 2 bytes longer (51 bytes) and generates the file `o.png`. For the input `5\n4` it generates the following picture:

[image: Houndstooth Pattern]

### Explanation:

The Houndstooth Pattern looks really quite irregular. But if we bring the left 7 columns to the right and the top 5 rows to the botton we get a much nicer pattern:

```
.#####...................
..#####..................
...#####.................
....#####................
.....#####...............
#.....#####..............
##.....#####.............
###.....#####............
####.....####............
#####.....###............
######.....##............
#######.....#............
########.................
#############.....#######
##############.....######
###############.....#####
################.....####
#################.....###
##################.....##
#############.#####.....#
#############..#####.....
#############...#####....
#############....#####...
#############.....#####..
#############......#####.
#############.......#####
```

First I produce the top-left 13x13 block:

```
.#####.......
..#####......
...#####.....
....#####....
.....#####...
#.....#####..
##.....#####.
###.....#####
####.....####
#####.....###
######.....##
#######.....#
########.....
```

There are 2 simple inequalities, that describe the two `#`-areas. The band can be described by `y + 1 <= x <= y + 5` and the triangle can be described by `x <= y - 5`. I`ve combined these two conditions:

```
Jmms}k++Rhd5U-d4T=T13
                 =T13   T = 13
 m               T      map each d of [0, 1, ..., 12] to: 
                           the list produced by
  m             T          map each k of [0, 1, ..., 12] to:
       +Rhd5                  the list [d+1, d+2, ..., d+5]
      +                       extended by 
            U-d4              the list [0, 1, ..., d - 5]
    }k                        test if k is in the list
   s                          and convert the boolean result to 1 or 0
J                       assign this 13x13 block to J
```

Then `+Rm012` adds 12 zeros at the end of each row , to get the upper 25x13 block.

The lower 25x13 block is now really simple:

```
+Lm1T_mP_dJ
      m   J    map each row d of J to:
       P_d        reverse the row and pop the last element
     _         reverse the order the rows
+Lm1T          add T ones at the beginning of each row.
```

All now left is to repeating the pattern and print it

```
j*vwmjk*Qd+upperlower   implicit: Q = first input number
          +upperlower   combine the two blocks to a 25x26 block
    m                   map each row d to:
       *Qd                 repeat d Q times
     jk                    and join to a string
 *vw                    read another number from input and repeat
j                       join by newlines and print
```

The difference to the **Cookie bonus** code:

- `255` instead of `1`
- instead of `mjk*Qd` I use `*RQ`, since I don't want a string
- `.w` saves this 2D-array to file (converts it to png implicitly)

Comment: Fantastic explanation!

Comment: You clearly mean "bottom 5 rows to the top", it's just a typo. I don't understand why my comment was deleted without action being taken. As a result I'm shy to go and edit your post myself now. All in all, a very good answer and an excellent explanation. I already upvoted it before

Comment: @steveverrill Oh, sorry. I thought you wanted to correct my English in the passage, in which I described the transformation back. Fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, <s>106</s> <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```
0000000: 71 7e 22 04 94 51 af 40 6e 73 b2 68 3a e1 7e 13 f2 a1  q~"..Q.@ns.h:.~...
0000012: 3e 1d de f5 64 9c 6b 0f 27 4c 36 d7 81 3d 30 35 56 f8  >...d.k.'L6..=05V.
0000024: cd e8 cd 7c dc 90 31 59 40 8b 8c 22 32 35 36 62 32 32  ...|..1Y@.."256b22
0000036: 62 41 73 33 39 2a 2e 2a 73 32 35 2f 2a 66 2a 4e 2a     bAs39*.*s25/*f*N*
```

Prints `1` and `0` instead of `.` and `#`. Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%22%04%C2%94Q%C2%AF%40ns%C2%B2h%3A%C3%A1~%13%C3%B2%C2%A1%3E%1D%C3%9E%C3%B5d%C2%9Ck%0F'L6%C3%97%C2%81%3D05V%C3%B8%C3%8D%C3%A8%C3%8D%7C%C3%9C%C2%901Y%40%C2%8B%C2%8C%22256b22bAs39*.*s25%2F*f*N*&input=5%204).

#### How it works

```
q~      e# Read and evaluate all input. This pushes W and H.
"…"     e# Push an encoding of run lengths of the characters in the output.
256b22b e# Convert from base 256 to base 22.
As39*   e# Push "10" and repeat it 39 times.
.*      e# Vectorized character repetition; multiply each base 22 digit (run
        e# length) by the corresponding character of "10…10".
s25/    e# Flatten and split into chunks of length 25.
*       e# Repeat the resulting array of rows H times.
f*      e# Repeat each row W times.
N*      e# Join the rows, separating by linefeeds.
```

#### Cookie bonus

```
0000000: 27 50 6f 31 70 71 7e 5d 5f 5b 32 35 5f 29 5d 2e 2a 5c  'Po1pq~]_[25_)].*\
0000012: 7e 22 04 94 51 af 40 6e 73 b2 68 3a e1 7e 13 f2 a1 3e  ~"..Q.@ns.h:.~...>
0000024: 1d de f5 64 9c 6b 0f 27 4c 36 d7 81 3d 30 35 56 f8 cd  ...d.k.'L6..=05V..
0000036: e8 cd 7c dc 90 31 59 40 8b 8c 22 32 35 36 62 32 32 62  ..|..1Y@.."256b22b
0000048: 41 73 33 39 2a 2e 2a 73 32 35 2f 2a 66 2a 73 2b 4e 2a  As39*.*s25/*f*s+N*
```

prints a Portable BitMap instead of ASCII art.

Below is the output for input `24 13`, converted to PNG:

[image: output]

Answer (score 7):

## [Befunge-93](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), <s>2120</s> 1967 bytes

Here's some high quality befunge, with exception-handling for debugging!

```
&&00p10pv
v       <
    >94+2*20p        v
>00g|   >                v
    @                >10g>0020gv-1:<
                               >:0`|
                     ,       v    $<
                     +        >v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v
 v_$1-:#^_$20g1-20p55^       >|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>"!DAB"....@
 ,:
 >^".......#.....#####......."                                                    <
  ^".......##.....#####......"                                                  <
  ^".......###.....#####....."                                                <
  ^".......####.....####....."                                              <
  ^".......#####.....###....."                                            <
  ^".......######.....##....."                                          <
  ^".......#######.....#....."                                        <
  ^".......########.........."                                      <
  ^"####################....."                                    <
  ^".####################...."                                  <
  ^"..####################..."                                <
  ^"...####################.."                              <
  ^"....####################."                            <
  ^".....####################"                          <
  ^"#.....##############.####"                        <
  ^"##.....#############..###"                      <
  ^"###....#############...##"                    <
  ^"####...#############....#"                  <
  ^"#####..#############....."                <
  ^".#####.#############....."              <
  ^"..##################....."            <
  ^"........#####............"          <
  ^".........#####..........."        <
  ^"..........#####.........."      <
  ^"...........#####........."    <
  ^"............#####........"  <
^                     p00-1g00<
```

(Obviously, this is still very golfable.  I just wanted to get an answer up here for now)

So, this is made up of different parts.

```
&&00p10p
```

This is just the initializer, it takes in the values and stores them

```
    >94+2*20p
>00g|      > 
    @
```

This section resets the row count, so we can print out another (width) pictures side by side.  `94+2*` is calculating 26, the number of rows.  Also, if the height is zero, the program will terminate.

```
>10g
```

This gets the width on the stack so we know how many to print

```
0020gv-1:<
     >:0`|
         $
```

This adds two dummy values to the stack to tell when we've finished an operation, as well as what row (n) we're on.  This then adds n values to the stack

```
>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v>v
|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>|>"!DAB"....@

                                                    <
                                                  <
                                                <
                                              <
                                            <
                                          <
                                        <
                                      <
                                    <
                                  <
                                <
                              <
                            <
                          <
                        <
                      <
                    <
                  <
                <
              <
            <
          <
        <
      <
    <
  <
<
```

This is a control section that will to the (26-n) row.  This is the easiest way i could figure out how to do it.

```
".......#.....#####......."
".......##.....#####......"
".......###.....#####....."
".......####.....####....."
".......#####.....###....."
".......######.....##....."
".......#######.....#....."
".......########.........."
"####################....."
".####################...."
"..####################..."
"...####################.."
"....####################."
".....####################"
"#.....##############.####"
"##.....#############..###"
"###....#############...##"
"####...#############....#"
"#####..#############....."
".#####.#############....."
"..##################....."
"........#####............"
".........#####..........."
"..........#####.........."
"...........#####........."
"............#####........"
```

This, obviously, is read and will pop whatever row is read onto the stack backwards.  This means when we pop it off, it will print properly.

```
v_
,:
>^
```

This will print until the stack hits a 0, which we left on earlier.

```
1-:#^_
```

This takes 1 off of the number of the specific line to print, then checks if it's zero or not.  If it's non-zero, we go back to the fourth block of code.

```
          ,
          +
20g1-20p55^
```

This subtracts 1 from the row (n), prints a newline, and goes back to block 3

```
p00-1g00
```

Once of all of the rows have printed, this subtracts one from the initial height and goes back to block 2.

All the rest of the code is either control flow or stack management.  Writing this mas more than I thought it would be, but I'm satisfied with how it looks.  It's much more golfable, and that will likely remain a project for another day.

**2120 -> 1967**: trimmed up some lines with a lot of wasted spaces

Comment: [I golfed it.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58577/12914) Not your answer specifically, but I golfed a solution in Befunge!

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 243

(One byte added for the `-n` switch to fetch input from stdin.)

```perl
($w,$h)=split;for(1..$h){print((sprintf("%025b",hex)x$w).$/)foreach qw(20f80 307c0 383e0 3c1e0 3e0e0 3f060 3f820 3fc00 1ffffe0 fffff0 7ffff8 3ffffc 1ffffe fffff 107ffef 183ffe7 1c3ffe3 1e3ffe1 1f3ffe0 fbffe0 7fffe0 1f000 f800 7c00 3e00 1f00)}
```

This is fairly straightforward — all it does is convert an array of 26 hex numbers to binary and print them out the required number of times.

#### Example:

Input:

```
3 2
```

Output:

```
000000010000011111000000000000001000001111100000000000000100000111110000000
000000011000001111100000000000001100000111110000000000000110000011111000000
000000011100000111110000000000001110000011111000000000000111000001111100000
000000011110000011110000000000001111000001111000000000000111100000111100000
000000011111000001110000000000001111100000111000000000000111110000011100000
000000011111100000110000000000001111110000011000000000000111111000001100000
000000011111110000010000000000001111111000001000000000000111111100000100000
000000011111111000000000000000001111111100000000000000000111111110000000000
111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100000
011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110000
001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111000
000111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100
000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110
000001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111
100000111111111111110111110000011111111111111011111000001111111111111101111
110000011111111111110011111000001111111111111001111100000111111111111100111
111000011111111111110001111100001111111111111000111110000111111111111100011
111100011111111111110000111110001111111111111000011111000111111111111100001
111110011111111111110000011111001111111111111000001111100111111111111100000
011111011111111111110000001111101111111111111000000111110111111111111100000
001111111111111111110000000111111111111111111000000011111111111111111100000
000000001111100000000000000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000000
000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000000000000001111100000000000
000000000011111000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000111110000000000
000000000001111100000000000000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000
000000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000000000000001111100000000
000000010000011111000000000000001000001111100000000000000100000111110000000
000000011000001111100000000000001100000111110000000000000110000011111000000
000000011100000111110000000000001110000011111000000000000111000001111100000
000000011110000011110000000000001111000001111000000000000111100000111100000
000000011111000001110000000000001111100000111000000000000111110000011100000
000000011111100000110000000000001111110000011000000000000111111000001100000
000000011111110000010000000000001111111000001000000000000111111100000100000
000000011111111000000000000000001111111100000000000000000111111110000000000
111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100000
011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110000
001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111000
000111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100
000011111111111111111111000001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110
000001111111111111111111100000111111111111111111110000011111111111111111111
100000111111111111110111110000011111111111111011111000001111111111111101111
110000011111111111110011111000001111111111111001111100000111111111111100111
111000011111111111110001111100001111111111111000111110000111111111111100011
111100011111111111110000111110001111111111111000011111000111111111111100001
111110011111111111110000011111001111111111111000001111100111111111111100000
011111011111111111110000001111101111111111111000000111110111111111111100000
001111111111111111110000000111111111111111111000000011111111111111111100000
000000001111100000000000000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000000
000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000000000000001111100000000000
000000000011111000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000111110000000000
000000000001111100000000000000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000
000000000000111110000000000000000000011111000000000000000000001111100000000
```

Answer (score 3):

## Rev 1, C, <s>118</s> 115 bytes

```
i,x,y;f(w,h){for(i=26*h*(w*=25);i--;i%w||puts(""))x=i%25,y=i/w%26,putchar(((y>x^y>x+5^x>y+4)&y/13==x/13^y/13)+34);}
```

9 bytes saved due to new rule allowing translation of the cell. 3 bytes saved by use of `w*=25`. Rest of post remains unchanged.

## Rev 0, C, 127 bytes

```
i,x,y;f(w,h){for(i=650*w*h;i--;i%(25*w)||puts(""))x=(i+20)%25,y=(i/25/w+8)%26,putchar(((y>x^y>x+5^x>y+4)&y/13==x/13^y/13)+34);}
```

This goes through the characters, printing them one by one. `i%(25*w)||puts("")` inserts a newline at the end of each line.

My way of viewing the design is similar to Jakube's, but I bring the top 8 rows to the bottom and the 5 right columns to the left to get the following view. In the program this step is "reversed" by `+20` and `+8` in the expressions for x and y.

```
"""""####################
#"""""###################
##"""""##################
###"""""#################
####"""""################
#####"""""###############
"#####"""""##############
""#####"""""#############
"""#####""""#############
""""#####"""#############
"""""#####""#############
""""""#####"#############
"""""""##################
"""""""""""""#####"""""""
""""""""""""""#####""""""
"""""""""""""""#####"""""
""""""""""""""""#####""""
"""""""""""""""""#####"""
""""""""""""#"""""#####""
""""""""""""##"""""#####"
""""""""""""###"""""#####
""""""""""""####"""""####
""""""""""""#####"""""###
""""""""""""######"""""##
""""""""""""#######"""""#
""""""""""""########"""""
```

Apart from the "inversion of colours" it may look very similar, but there is an important difference: the diagonal stripes match up. (note that the original design does not have diagonal symmetry as it measures 25x26.)

The expression `((y>x^y>x+5^x>y+4)^y/13)+34` produces the following, where the various comparison operators produce the stripes, the `^y/13` produces the "colour flip" half way up and the `+34` takes the resulting number `0,1` and boosts it to the ASCII range `34,35`.

```
"""""####################
#"""""###################
##"""""##################
###"""""#################
####"""""################
#####"""""###############
"#####"""""##############
""#####"""""#############
"""#####"""""############
""""#####"""""###########
"""""#####"""""##########
""""""#####"""""#########
"""""""#####"""""########
########"""""#####"""""""
#########"""""#####""""""
##########"""""#####"""""
###########"""""#####""""
############"""""#####"""
#############"""""#####""
##############"""""#####"
###############"""""#####
################"""""####
#################"""""###
##################"""""##
###################"""""#
####################"""""
```

The term `&y/13==x/13` evaluates to false=0 in the top right and bottom left quarters, producing the square part of the pattern as shown previously. Note that because the program downcounts, the origin x=y=0 is at bottom right. This is handy as the square of `#` is 13 characters wide while the square of `"` is only 12 characters wide.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)-93, 968 bytes

Yes, that's right! A competing Befunge answer!

```
&:&\00p10p:520pv:g00p02<v  <
    #   p1*45-1_v#:" "  <  v
    |`-1*65:g02$<      ,
    >:" "\39*\p:" "\47 *v
+:"<"\39*\p:"v"\47*\p25^>\p 1
".......#.....#####......."<v
".......##.....#####......"
".......###.....#####....."
".......####.....####....."
".......#####.....###....."
".......######.....##....."
".......#######.....#....."
".......########.........."
"####################....."
".####################...."
"..####################..."
"...####################.."
"....####################."
".....####################"
"#.....##############.####"
"##.....#############..###"
"###....#############...##"
"####...#############....#"
"#####..#############....."
".#####.#############....."
"..##################....."
"........#####............"
".........#####..........."
"..........#####.........."
"...........#####........."
"............#####........"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,  v>
    > 10g1-:10p #v_@
 " " \47*\p5:"<"v>:" "\39*\ p
\*74 \"v":p\*93\<      v,*5 2p
```

Explanation tomorrow, bed now. I will say, however, that I do clever stuff with moving a couple redirection arrows and I use the wrap-around property quite a bit too. Test it out in [this online interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html).